# Использование переменных при запросе GraphQl

Tags: java, graphql

Для запроса на другой сервис использую GraphQL.
Для составления конкретного запроса в коде использую кодогенератор, который билдит документ с запросом.

Вопрос в том, что не могу найти информацию о том, как использовать этот документ с использованием переменных?

К примеру вот сформированный Query

```
var query = OrganisationGraphQLQuery
            .newRequest()
            .queryName("query_example")
            .id(id)
            .build();
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при запросе использовался не просто id, а id подставленный как переменный.

Вот схема описания:

```
type Query {
    organisation ($id: ID!): [Organisation]
}

 type Organisation {
     inn: String
     ogrn: String
 }
```